# At what age one stops calling a person 孩子？

Tags: simplified-characters

I've seen a text where 20-year-old woman was called 女孩子, is it usual in China?

The text I'm referring to:

> 我大哥认识一个女孩子，她的名字叫李明英。李小姐今年二十岁，是大学生

Comment: certainly, happens all the time in newscasts, TV dramas etc. also see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/25611/can-i-use-%e5%a5%b3-%e5%ad%a9%e5%ad%90-even-if-the-person-in-question-is-an-adult/25634#25634

Comment: some users are wondering whether 男孩子 in quoted text should not be 女孩子 (她 instead of 他?) male gender individuals may be called 男孩子 although not as often,小伙子 may be more common, although perhaps implying greater degree of familiarity

Comment: To your parents and your grandparents， you're 孩子 forever.

Comment: where 孩子 means that not-married other than child.

Comment: There should be 女孩子 indeed, i was typing in hurry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when some young adult talk such subject, it possibly refer to “not married（never married）” other than “child”, especially there are romatic or marriage related stories.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think these sentences are related? I think they are 2 different, unrelated sentences.

1. 我大哥认识一个男孩子，他个名字叫李明英。
   My big brother knows a boy whose name is Li Mingying
2. 李小姐今年二十岁，是大学生。
   Miss Li will be 20 years old this year, she is a student at university.

小姐 = Miss
男孩子 = boy

Comment: My bad, I was typing in hurry, now sentence should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

> 我大哥认识一个男孩子，他个名字叫李明英。李小姐今年二十岁，是大学生

I try to correct your text as below:

> 我大哥认识一个**女孩子**，**她的**名字叫李明英。李小姐今年二十岁，是大学生

To your specific question, when we were in the college, we were in the age of the 20s and we often call ourselves 男孩子 or 女孩子. For example, 女孩子喜欢个子高的男孩子.

Generally, you can call a teenage or one in the age of puberty 男孩子 or 女孩子.

The line at which they were not called 孩子 is obscure indeed. The circumstances , contexts and perspectives play important roles in this.

Comment: in other words 这位尊敬的用户 supports comment #2

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of people in China, you are a 女孩子 until you are married, but there isn't a specific defining mark. I would roughly say around age 30 or upon marriage (whichever occurs first) is when a single person stops being a 孩子, but that is a very rough heuristic.

Try thinking of it less like "female child" and more like "girl."